# How to get EFProf and EFProviderWrapper working together in on Entity Framework Connection

Tags: entity-framework-4, dbconnection

Has anyone found a way to get [Kowalski's EFProviderWrapper framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers) to run alongside [Rhino's EFProf](http://efprof.com/home) (Entity Framework Profiler) within the same Entity Framework context/connection? Currently if i try to register the EFProf Profiler while using an EntitytConnection wrapped with the EFProviderWrapper i get the following error at runtime when a new connection is attempted to be created:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.ProfiledDataAccess.ProfiledConnection'
>   to type
>   'EFProviderWrapperToolkit.DbConnectionWrapper'.

From what I can gether it appears to be because EFProf is registering last, and EFProviderWrapperToolkit expects to be the last one registered. Im guessing that this requires a change to EFProviderWrapperToolkit possibly to create a new DbConnectionWrapper type that allows for non-EFProviderWrapper types? If anyone has any experience with multiple DBConnection provider frameworks then im all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 years of inactivity I'm pretty certain the answer is:

**Probably no.**